# In Swift, how do I explicitly specify a return value for map with anonymous closure arguments?

Tags: swift, dictionary, return, arguments

Say I call `map` like this, using the anonymous closure argument `$0`:

```swift
array.map {
  return $0.description
}
```

How would I explicitly define that map returns a `string`? This doesn’t work:

```swift
array.map { -> String
  return $0.description
}
```

> Contextual type for closure argument list expects 1 argument, which cannot be implicitly ignored

Does that mean if I want to specify a return value I have to name my arguments?

[EDIT: I know I do not need an explicit return type here; still would like how to specify one]

Comment: _"Does that mean if I want to specify a return value I have to name my arguments?"_ Yes. Or if your closure is only a single line, the compiler will be able to infer the return type itself.

Comment: isnt description a string ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `as` to identify the type of the anonymous enclosure.  In this case you'll need to specify the type of the input as well:

```
let result = array.map({ $0.description } as (CustomStringConvertible) -> String)
```

**Note:**  You could use the type of whatever is in `array` as the input type.  Here I just used the `CustomStringConvertible` protocol since that is what is needed to be able to access the `.description` property.

or as you mentioned, you can specify the output type if you give a name to the input parameter:

```
let result = array.map { value -> String in value.description }
```

---

Another way to look at it is to note that `map` returns an `Array` of whatever type the `map` closure returns.  You could specify that the result of the map is `[String]` and Swift would then infer that the `map` closure returns `String`:

```
let result = array.map({ $0.description }) as [String]
```

or

```
let result: [String] = array.map { $0.description }
```

Answer (score -1):

The type will be inferred automatically if it's a string , otherwise you need a cast like this

```
array.map { String($0.description) }
```