# Adding inline explicit type annotations to a closure with a return value but no input parameters in Swift?

Tags: swift, syntax, closures, implicit-typing

Normally a function doesn't need explicit types since it can infer the type from the context:

```
let f = { input in
  1 + input
}
f(2)
```

Oftentimes you need to provide an [explicit type annotation](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/tips/explicit-type-annotations/) to force it to use a specific type, or in case the compiler cannot infer the type. This is straightforward when you have an input parameter:

```
let f = { (input: Double) -> Double in
  1 + input
}
f(2)
```

However, if you don't have an input parameter, I'm not sure what the syntax is supposed to look like:

```
let f = { -> Double in
  1 + 1
}
f()
```

> error: Expected expression

I tried all of these variations to no avail:

- `let f = { -> Double in`: "error: Expected expression"
- `let f = { _ -> Double in`: "error: unable to infer type of a closure parameter '_' in the current context", this also changes it to take in an argument, which is not what I want.
- `let f = { Void -> Double in`: "error: unable to infer type of a closure parameter 'Void' in the current context"
- `let f = { Never -> Double in`: "error: unable to infer type of a closure parameter 'Never' in the current context"

I was able to get it working by [adding an `as` clause to the end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60304253/in-swift-how-do-i-explicitly-specify-a-return-value-for-map-with-anonymous-clos), but this seems verbose and like an oversight if there's no way to define just an explicit return type for a closure using this syntax.

```
let f = {
  1 + 1
} as () -> Double
f()
```

How do I define an explicit return type for a closure (using inline syntax instead of `as`), if it has no input parameters?

---

Note: I'm happy to close this as a duplicate if another question already exists. (I tried searching for duplicates using the terms `explicit type annotation closure return only` and couldn't find anything relevant.)

Comment: Also: `let f: () -> Double = { ... }`

Comment: You were quite close when writing `let f = { ... } as () -> Double` !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The empty tuple `()` indicates an empty argument list:

```
let f = { () -> Double in
  1 + 1
}

print(f()) // 2.0
```

`()` can be both a *type* (identical to `Void`)  and an *instance* of that type:

```
let a: Void = ()
let b: () = ()
print(type(of: a) == type(of: b)) // true
```

Comment: Ah thanks! I thought that `()` means the same thing as `Void`, so I didn't try that variation.

Comment: @Senseful: `()` can be both a type (identical to `Void`)  and an *instance* of that type.